# Python: call and run a process with input files

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, launch

I am looking for a solution to run a process with input files in python:
in my script I call a process using sub-process:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(['C:\EnergyPlusV8-8-0\EP-Launch.exe'])
```

So the program I would like to launch is open, but then I need to choose 2 input files and then press the button `"Simulate.."` to execute the program(Energy Plus).

***comment:
I mean, after those code lines, the interface of the program(Energy Plus) is open, then I choose in that window which input files the program has to use. After that in the same interface of the program I start the simulation. I want to do these steps just in the python code, without interacte with the EnergyPlus interface. I hope I clearify the ambiguities
I would like to do the last steps automatically(knowing the input files location) in the python code.
How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"a process with input files"*?  Also what do you mean by *"press the button "Simulate..""*?  And what do you mean by *"the program I would like to launch is open" ... "press the button "Simulate.." to execute the program(Energy Plus)."*

Comment: Most likely you need to arrange all the inputs first and then start the EP process as the final step.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this unless EnergyPlus is providing some kind of API, or you are prepared to write UI manipulation code, which would really depend on the type of application it is. Without more information I'm going to have to say what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: Are you sure there not an easy way to do that? Because I noticed that every time I launch Energy Plus it opens with the default files. So I changed the inputs with the ones I want. The problem that still remains is to "push" the `"Simulate.."` button on the Energy Plus GUI